# haproxy subdomain access for CORS

Tags: cors, haproxy

I want to do the equivalent of this in haproxy to allow CORS for any server in my domain. By default CORS only does null, star or a single URL. Is that possible? Here's what works on apache:

```
 SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.bebop\.co)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
```

I've already added the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and set it to true so just need that one more piece. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured some things out that answer my question. The equivelant of above is to add in the frontend section:

```
frontend
...
...
# CORS Config Capture
capture request header origin len 50
```

and on the backend:

```
backend
...
...
http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to allow it for a specific sub-domain, but for any origin header that comes in.